# Monomorphism in one of the component of pushout diagram implies other component is monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

[image]
<sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d1h3rn191q292q485j3424g45423d55.png))</sub>

Here our category is that of groups where first arrow between A and B is a monomorphism. Does that imply that the lower bottom arrow is a monomorphism ? That is the arrow between B and C. Here the diagram is a pushout diagram.

Comment: It works in the category of abelian groups (more generally in abelian categories). I don't think it does in general in the category of groups, however; but can't find a counterexample on the top of my head